# React native Module: Failed to resolve: com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-core:2.7.3

Tags: android, react-native, exoplayer2.x

I am getting this eroor "Could not find dependency

> com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-core:2.7.3"

Any one have idea Why this Happen?

Answer (score 1):

After researching what i found is that something is wrong with the bintray.

Try this.

```
maven {url 'https://google.bintray.com/exoplayer/'}
```

You can refer [this](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/5225)

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed "r" before "2.7.3" ([check it](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/releases/tag/r2.7.3))
**try this:** `com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-core:r2.7.3`

Answer (score 0):

I have tried all the various things but nothing work for me.

In my case What helps me is put

```
include ':react-native-video'
project(':react-native-video').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-video/android-exoplayer')
```

in setting.gradle file.
I am not sure this is full proof answer but still it may help